# Rust segmentation fault in chrono

Tags: rust, segmentation-fault

When playing with Linux PAM and developing a sample library in Rust using some date-related logic, I encountered a segmentation fault when testing the `authenticate()` function with `pamtester`.

`Cargo.toml`:

```
...
[dependencies]
chrono = { version = "0.4.*", features = ["serde"] }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive debugging, I located the source of the segmentation fault to a variable determining the current date:

```
use ::chrono::{NaiveDateTime, Local};

pub fn get_today() -> Result<NaiveDateTime, Error> {
    // this is the perpetrator
    let local_now: NaiveDateTime = Local::now().naive_local();
    if let Some(local_date) = local_now.date().and_hms_opt(0, 0, 0) {
        return Ok(local_date);
    }
    else {
        Err(Error::new("Cannot get today's date!"))
    }
}
```

And searching for issue in `chrono` causing segmentation fault, I found that `chrono` is still depending on `time 0.1` that can cause segmentation faults under some special circumstances; and that [updating `chrono` to a more recent version of `time` is a bit difficult](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/qamgyh/is_the_chrono_crate_unmaintained/).

There is a [Rust advisory](https://github.com/RustSec/advisory-db/blob/main/crates/time/RUSTSEC-2020-0071.md) that suggests a solution: to disable the default features and only enable specific ones:
`Cargo.toml`

```
...
[dependencies]
chrono = { version = "0.4.*", default-features = false, features = ["serde", "clock"] }
...
```

Using this fix, no more segmentation faults in `pamtester`.

*(Haven't found anything about it in SO, so sharing for someone else not to spend a few nights tearing their hair :-) )*

Comment: I recommend you add `cargo audit` to your CI config, It would have told you.